# C# Uri.CheckHostName(String) Method not working?

Tags: c#, uri

can someone explain me why I got this behavior when using Uri.CheckHostName(String) Method in c# like this :

```
Console.WriteLine(Uri.CheckHostName("10"));
```

Output : IPv4

```
Console.WriteLine(Uri.CheckHostName("F"));
```

Output : DNS

As you can see their not valid IPv4 or DNS values...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.checkhostname?view=net-5.0

Comment: On most systems `F` would be a name that would be looked up through DNS, while `10` would be interpreted as `0.0.0.10`. In that sense, what the method returns is "correct", for some relatively unhelpful values of "correct".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the [code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/_DomainName.cs,68) called by [Uri.CheckHostName](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/URI.cs,1355), which includes this comment:

```
//  Determines whether a string is a valid domain name label. In keeping
//  with RFC 1123, section 2.1, the requirement that the first character
//  of a label be alphabetic is dropped. Therefore, Domain names are
//  formed as:
//
//      <label> -> <alphanum> [<alphanum> | <hyphen> | <underscore>] * 62
```

Emphasis on this line:

> the requirement that the first character of a [DNS] label be
> alphabetic is dropped.

That method also calls this [code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/_DomainName.cs,504) to check for valid characters.

In short, looks like it's working by design to me.